# PL/SQL function to check length and build a string

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have created a VIEW with a column containing aggregated values(stores the output in varchar2 data type). Some of the records exceed the maximum limit, for example varchar2(4000). I was suggested a PL/SQL function to check the length and build a string if necessary..

I've checked, and tried to correct the syntax errors,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION SUBURL(col1 IN VARCHAR2, col2 IN varchar2)
RETURN varchar2
IS
v_result_string varchar2(4000);
v_length varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
IF (length (col1) + length (col2) ... <= 4000) then return col1 || col2 || ...
END IF; 
-- build the string and check the length for every column you contatenate
v_result_string := col1;
if (length(v_result_string) + length (col2) > 4000) THEN
   -- add as much of col2 as you can up to a total of 4000
   v_length := 4000 - length(v_result_string);
   v_result_string := v_result_string  + substr(col2, 1, v_length);
   return v_result_string;
end if;
end suburl;
```

Two errors this time,

Error(7,35): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:     . ( ) , * % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem =>     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec as between || member submultiset The symbol "." was ignored.

Error(7,76): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new null          continue avg count current max min prior sql stddev sum    variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval date          pipe

Comment: Have you looked for the correct syntax of a pl/sql function?

Comment: Now you're missing the semicolon after the definition of the `v_length` variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of syntax errors in your code.

- First, is your function supposed to accept an argument?  You have an open paren after the function name `FUNCTION suburl(` which implies that you do expect to pass in a parameter.  But then you don't declare a parameter, you just start in with the body of your function.  Either remove that open paren or add the declaration of the parameter(s) you want to pass in.
- Second, you are using local variables `v_length` and `v_result_string` that are not declared.  You would need to declare those.  If `v_resultl_string` is supposed to be a third variable rather than a misspelling of `v_result_string`, you'd need to declare that as well.
- Third, you are missing the `BEGIN` and `END` that begins and ends the body of the function

The skeleton of a function declaration is something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION name_of_function( parameter_list )
IS
  variable_declarations;
BEGIN
  body_of_function;
END;
```

Beyond that, there are a number of syntax errors in the body of your code with unmatched parenthesis.

```
if (length(v_result_string) + length (col2) > 4000 THEN
```

for example, is missing a close paren before the `THEN`

```
if (length(v_result_string) + length (col2) > 4000)
then
```

What are the ellipses in your code supposed to represent?  Are you concatenating more than just the `col1` and `col2` columns?  The code path you're following if concatenating the columns results in a string longer than 4000 bytes makes very little sense to me as it stands.  It can be simplified if you are only trying to concatentate the two columns but if there are more columns then you'd need to account for those as well.

You used the word "aggregation" which implies that you want to combine the data from multiple different *rows*, not multiple different *columns*.  If that is, in fact, what you are trying to accomplish, you could use a loop or you could write a user-defined aggregate function.

Comment: @user1888543 - Sorry, I'm not sure that I follow your comment.  If you want to post modified code, please edit your question and modify the code there.  If you are saying that you are still getting compilation errors, please include the new set of error messages.

Comment: I've edited the previous query on the top.